# XAML Hub Control Windows 8.1 Universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

Why is the hub control in Windows 8.1 seems like its taking an additional 120 pixel up top?

I have nested my Hub control as follows:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource DmWhiteBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <controls:TopNavigationBarControl Grid.Row="0" />

        <Hub
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="0"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"                 >
            <HubSection
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" > DATA BLA BLA
            </HubSection>
```

And between my hub and my controls:TopNavigationBarControl  there seems to be about 120 extra pixels, i have found nothing better then to add a negative top margin on the hub element, but thats not great.  Does anyone have an idea of what i can do to remove this?  I do not want to use the header in the hub element.  thx!

EDIT:
As of right now i have found nothing better then to edit the template of the hub and remove the header and remove the top padding using blend.  Also on the hub element i have added

```
<Hub
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Margin="0">
```

Edit2: In blend I cant find where are those extra pixels!, I can clearly see that there is still a space for a header, even thought I have removed the grids row definition in blend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will also need to remove the `Padding` for each `HubSection`.

This is its default padding of the `HubSection` conrol.

```
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="40,40,40,44"/>
```

Changing the second `40` to `0` will collapse all the space in between.

```
<HubSection Header="HubSection 0" Padding="40,0,40,44">
```

**Update**

This is the code and how it looks like on the designer. When I run it it looks exactly the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yup i have already removed these thanks to using blend and creating a template from the current item.

Comment: @Damien, I just uploaded the screenshot and the code. See there's no space in between for hub section 1.